# passing an array to a function pointer from C#

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I've implemented some functions in C program and wrap it into a dll, which will be called in another C# project. One of the function in the dll takes a function pointer as an input argument, i.e., in the source code generating the dll, one of the function looks like:

```
void functionA(
    int* a,
    int* b,
    double *c,
    double[] inputArr,
    double[] outputtArr,
    void(*fun)(int*, int*,double[],double[])
)
```

Inside the functionA, the inputArr will be used as input to the function pointer and outputArr will be used as the output. The inputArr should has a dimension of *a and the size of outputtArr should be *b.

In C#, I tried to import the dll and invoke the functionA by following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Test{    
class Program
    {
     public delegate void costfun(ref int a, ref int b, double[] x, double[] fx);         
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 5, b = 3,
            double c= 1e-14

            double[] x = new double[5] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };                              
            double[] y= new double[3] { 100, 100, 100 };
            costfun F = new costfun(fun);
          functionA(ref a, ref b,  ref c, x,y  Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(F));

        }

        public static void fun(ref int na, ref int nb, double[] inX, double[] outY)
        {
            int i = 0;
            outY= new double[nb];

            if (outY.Length != nb)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("output incorrect");
                return;
            }
            if (inX.Length != na)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("input incorrect");
                return;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < nb; i++)
            { outY[i] = inX[i] * inX[i + 1] + 1; }
        }

        // import the dll
        [DllImport("cdll.dll", EntryPoint = "functionA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]    
        public static extern void functionA(int* a, int* b, double*c,double[] inputArr, double[] outputtArr, IntPtr fcpointer);
}
}
```

The program is successfully compiled an can be executed. yet I found during the execution, whenever the function fun is invoked from the dll, the input array inX only has a single element, that is only inX[0] is passed. If I comment the two if statement inside the function fun, visual studio will break due to an index out of bound exception occurred in the statement:

```
outY[i] = inX[i] * inX[i + 1] + 1;
```

because of inX[i+1].Can anyone gives me some hints how to tackle this problem? Thanks

Comment: What is the code inside your c function? It appears that is where your issue would lie since it controls the values returned.

Comment: Sounds like you need to call `DynamicInvoke` on the delegate. Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307018/3516555

Comment: Can you try passing it as a pointer

Comment: @bhmahler: inside the c function, the pointer a, b and the array inputArr, outputtArr are passed to the function specified by the function pointer. You can think the function in C as an optimizer and the function pointer as the cost function.

Comment: @Gauravsa you mean changing the input argument of the function pointer from array to pointer? I've tried that, the result is the same. That is , inX only has a single element

Comment: Use the attribute on your delegate as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7436856/4228458)

Comment: @CodingYoshi You mean the attribute [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] ? I've tried that, the result is still the same, indexOutofRange Exception

Comment: Well you need to debug your code. Your code is extremely hard to read because you have given all the variables very unfriendly names. Also, we don't know what you are doing in the C code because you have not posted that.

Comment: @Eric: instead of double[], u can pass in double* for both input and output arrays

Comment: @Gauravsa Thx for your suggestion. I tried to modify the declaration of functionA in C, replacing the both array inputs to the function pointer with two pointers. If I do not change the inputs to the delegate in C#, the result is the same. If I need to change the delegate argument, then what data type should be put in place of the original double[] x, double[] fx?